# Как проверить что WebView изменил title и сделать переход на второй ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, веб-программирование, view, парсер

Создал такой код.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staging.api.kiteflightapp.com/webviews/buy_credits/index/9"];

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

```
self.element = elementName;
if([self.element isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    self.title = [NSMutableString string];

}


self.buttonPurchase = elementName;
if ([self.buttonPurchase isEqualToString:@"button"]) {
    self.resultPurchase = [NSMutableString string];
}
```

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

```
if (!self.element) return;
if([self.element isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    self.title = string;
}
```

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

```
if([self.element isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.title);
}

self.title=nil;
```

}

Необходимо перенаправить на другой ViewController если title = "Success".
Спарсил страницу, импортировал класс того контроллера куда нужно перейти.Инициализировал.
Пробовал через performSegue. Не работает.
Кто-то сталкивался?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без парсинга HTML. По окончанию загрузки web view достаточно вытащить заголовок документа яваскриптом:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSString *theTitle=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

Но я так понимаю проблема именно в переходе. Тут вероятно парвер просто работает а бекграунд потоке и оттуда же вызывает пуш контроллера, что неправильно (хотя я не скажу в каком именно потоке будет происходить парсинг). Если проблема в этом, то достаточно просто вызвать обновление UI в главном потоке, например:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
    // или performSegue
});
```

Ну и опять же стоит убедиться, что контроллер инициализирован правильно, из описания не очень пнятно в какой именно момент происходит отказ

Comment: да, проблема в переходе.Отказ происходит в момент когда парсинг данных окончен, я ввожу на webView информацию , нажимаю "Next". После этого происходит переход на другой url с информацией. 
И вот после того как я увидел информацию - мне необходимо перейти на другой viewController.

Comment: Поставь брейкпойнт в тот момент, когда должен произойти переход на друго контроллер и посмотри какой там поток: главный или нет. Второй - выполни код перехода на другой котроллер, например, по нахатию на кнопку. Если он сработает - значит проблема в том, как он выполняется, если нет - значит сам код не работает и проблема с парсингом не связана вовсе

Comment: проблема именно в коде перехода. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @VladislavHodeev не забудьте принять ответ